# How does GitHub assign numbers to issues, pull requests and discussions?

Tags: github, pull-request, github-issues

I am quite sure that GitHub uses the same counter for issues, pull requests and discussions.

If I create an issue in a fresh new repository, its number would be #1. Then, if I want to create a pull request, the number assigned to it would be #2. Similarly if I then create a discussion, its number would be #3.

I just wanted to get some sort of confirmation for my guess but couldn't find any in the GitHub docs.

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: I don't know about discussions, or if there's any official confirmation that IDs will be sequential, but Pull Requests seem to be implemented as a special type of Issue, see e.g. the notes on this page https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues

Comment: Not a confirmation but they says you can use '#' prefix to reference an issue or a pr. Link: 
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#referencing-issues-and-pull-requests